# Google Visualization Event Listeners Trigger in Cumulative

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a table which behaves correctly until I use the Category Picker.

Correct Behavior: When clicking on a row the table, the "selected" event triggers.  When sorting a column, the "sort" event triggers.

The event listener for the Proxy Table problematic.  I loose the behavior from the initial table draw.

My question is when the Category Picker is utilized to reduce the table, my correct behavior ends.

Problematic Behavior: 1. Filter for a "Gender", 2. Click on a row in the table 3. the "selected" event triggers two times.  Why?
When you filter for another "Gender", click on a row in the table, the "selected" event triggers three times.

This additive problem will continue for all Gender filters.

How can I make this stop?  Below is what I have so far.

Thanks as always for a bit of direction.

======
UPDATE:

All changes are tagged UPDATED in the code snippet.  Here is the summary:

1. Changed per White Hat ProxyTable event listener that contains the "select" listener.

   `//UPDATED changed to .addOneTimeListener google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(proxyTable, 'ready', function() {`
2. Removed redrawTable() from ProxyTable listener that contains the "select" listener

   `//UPDATE removed from one time listener`
   `//redrawTable();`
3. Added new .addListener for ProxyTable to redrawTable()

   `//UPDATE Added separate listener to redraw the table  google.visualization.events.addListener(proxyTable, 'ready', function() { console.log(".addListener(proxyTable, 'ready' - redrawTable()"); redrawTable(); });`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls', 'charteditor']
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  //console.log("ready!");
  renderChart_onPageLoad();
});

function renderChart_onPageLoad() {
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    //console.log("renderChart_onPageLoad");
    drawDashboard();
  });
}

function drawDashboard() {
  //console.log("drawDashboard");

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'RoolNumber', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Donuts eaten'],
    ['Michael', 1, 'Male', 12, 5],
    ['Elisa', 2, 'Female', 20, 7],
    ['Robert', 3, 'Male', 7, 3],
    ['John', 4, 'Male', 54, 2],
    ['Jessica', 5, 'Female', 22, 6],
    ['Aaron', 6, 'Male', 3, 1],
    ['Margareth', 7, 'Female', 42, 8],
    ['Miranda', 8, 'Female', 33, 6]
  ]);

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

  var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'categoryPicker',
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'Gender',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false
      }
    }
  });

  var proxyTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'div_proxyTable',
    options: {
      width: '500px'
    }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'div_table',
    options: {
      sort: 'event', // <-- set sort to 'event' for table totaling
      width: '500px',
      allowHtml: true,
      page: 'enable',
      pageSize: '5',
    }
  });

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(proxyTable, 'ready', function() {
    console.log(".addOneTimeListener(proxyTable, 'ready' - sort");

    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(table, 'ready', function() {
      console.log(".addOneTimeListener(table, 'ready' - sort");

      //#region table - sort: 'event'
      google.visualization.events.addListener(table.getChart(), 'sort', function(sender) {
        console.log(".addListener(table.getChart(), 'sort' - sorted");

        //// update table --> options must include (sort: 'event') for total row to work properly
        //// update var grandTotal = tableData.getFilteredRows([{column: 0,
        //// update .draw() 'table' references to new name if using for a different table variable

        // sort data table according to sort properties
        var tableData = table.getDataTable();
        var sortIndexes = tableData.getSortedRows({
          column: sender.column,
          desc: !sender.ascending
        });

        //#region reposition total row - if required
        let totalRow = [];
        let hasTotalRow = true;
        if (hasTotalRow) {
          // find grand total row
          var grandTotal = tableData.getFilteredRows([{
            column: 0, //must be placed in a column which is of type string.
            value: "Grand Total"
          }]);
          if (grandTotal.length > 0) {
            // find grand total in sort
            var grandTotalSort = sortIndexes.indexOf(grandTotal[0]);

            // remove grand total from sort
            sortIndexes.splice(grandTotalSort, 1);

            // add grand total as first index
            sortIndexes.unshift(grandTotal[0]);
          }
        }
        //#endregion

        // set table sort arrow
        table.setOption('sortAscending', sender.ascending);
        table.setOption('sortColumn', sender.column);

        // set table view & re-draw table
        table.setView({
          rows: sortIndexes
        });
        table.draw();
      });
      //#endregion

    });
  });

//UPDATED changed to .addOneTimeListener
  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(proxyTable, 'ready', function() {
    console.log(".addOneTimeListener(proxyTable, 'ready' - select");

    let clickGetFunc = true;
    if (clickGetFunc !== undefined || clickGetFunc !== null) {

      google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(table, 'ready', function() {
        console.log(".addOneTimeListener(table, 'ready' - select");

        google.visualization.events.addListener(table.getChart(), 'select', function() {
          console.log(".addListener(table.getChart(), 'select' - selected");
          console.log("result of select");
          //lib_gcharts_selectedRowCol(table, json.tableChart.clickGetFunc);//(wrapperName, callback)
        });

      });
    }

//UPDATE removed from one time listener
    //redrawTable();
  });

//UPDATE Added separate listener to redraw the table 
 google.visualization.events.addListener(proxyTable, 'ready', function() {
    console.log(".addListener(proxyTable, 'ready' - redrawTable()");

   redrawTable();
   });

  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker], [proxyTable]);
  dashboard.draw(data);

  function redrawTable(tableChart) {
    console.log('redrawTable()');

    // set defaults for any undefined settings
    let dataView = [];
    let groupView = [];
    let totalRow = [];
    let conditionalFormat = [];

    // update .draw() 'table' or 'chart' references when using a different or additional chart name

    var sourceData = proxyTable.getDataTable().toDataTable().clone();
    //console.log('sourceData', sourceData);

    //#region create data view - this is used as basis for dataResults
    let view = new google.visualization.DataView(sourceData);

    //// set view columns
    //const viewColumns = [];
    //for (let i = 0; i < dataView.columns.length; i++) {
    //    viewColumns.push(
    //        viewColumn_default(view, dataView.columns[i]),
    //    );
    //};
    //view.setColumns(viewColumns);
    ////#endregion

    //#region set view filtering - if required
    let hasViewFilters = false;
    if (hasViewFilters) {

      const viewFilters = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < dataView.filters.columns.length; i++) {
        viewFilters.push(
          viewFilter_default(sourceData, dataView.filters.columns[i]),
        );
      };
      //console.log('viewFilter', viewFilter);

      const viewSetFilter = view.getFilteredRows(viewFilters);
      view.setRows(viewSetFilter);
    }
    //console.log('view'); console.log(view);
    //#endregion

    //#region create group view - if required
    let dataResults_forTable;
    let hasGroupView = false;
    if (hasGroupView) {

      // create keys for grouping
      const groupKeys = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < groupView.keys.length; i++) {
        groupKeys.push(
          groupKey_default(view, groupView.keys[i]),
        );
      };
      // create columns for aggregating
      const groupColumns = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < groupView.columns.length; i++) {
        groupColumns.push(
          groupColumn_default(view, groupView.columns[i]),
        );
      };

      // create data aggregation
      let group = google.visualization.data.group(view, groupKeys, groupColumns);
      //console.log('group'); console.log(group);

      let formatter;
      // set data column formatting - dynamically
      for (let i = 0; i < groupView.columns.length; i++) {
        formatter = dataColumn_format(groupView.columns[i].format);
        if (formatter !== null) {
          formatter.format(group, group.getColumnIndex(groupView.columns[i].id));
        }
      }
      //console.log('data'); console.log(data);

      // set data sorting    let hasGroupView = groupView.hasGroupView;
      let hasDataSorting = groupView.sorting.hasSorting;
      if (hasDataSorting) {
        const dataSort = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < groupView.sorting.columns.length; i++) {
          dataSort.push(
            dataSort_default(group, groupView.sorting.columns[i]),
          );
        };
        //console.log('dataSort', dataSort);
        group.sort(dataSort);
      }

      dataResults_forTable = group.clone();
    } else {
      dataResults_forTable = view.toDataTable().clone();
    } //END if (hasGroupView) {
    //console.log('dataResults_forTable', dataResults_forTable);

    //#endregion

    //#region create total row - if required
    let hasTotalRow = true;
    if (hasTotalRow) {

      let labelCol = "Total";
      let labelColIndex = 0;
      let totalColumns = 1;

      //Create groupColumns for total row aggregation calculations
      const groupColumns = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < totalColumns.length; i++) {
        const column = {
          column: dataResults_forTable.getColumnIndex(totalColumns),
          type: 'number'
        }
        switch ('sum') {
          case 'sum':
            column.aggregation = google.visualization.data.sum;
            break;
          case 'count':
            column.aggregation = google.visualization.data.count;
            break;
          case 'average':
            column.aggregation = google.visualization.data.avg;
            break;
          case 'min':
            column.aggregation = google.visualization.data.min;
            break;
          case 'max':
            column.aggregation = google.visualization.data.avg;
            break;
          default:
            column.aggregation = google.visualization.data.sum;
        }
        groupColumns.push(column);
      }

      let groupTotal = google.visualization.data.group(dataResults_forTable,
        // need key column to group on, so we want all rows grouped into 1, then it needs a constant value
        [{
          column: 0,
          type: "number",
          modifier: function() {
            return 1;
          }
        }], groupColumns);

      // this code block will run if the filter results in rows available to total.  Otherwise the table will present no rows.
      if (groupTotal.getNumberOfRows() !== 0) {

        let formatDecimal = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
          pattern: '#,###.##'
        });
        for (let i = 1; i < groupTotal.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
          formatDecimal.format(groupTotal, i);
        }

        // create Grand Total row from colToTotal and groupTotal
        const gtRow = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < dataResults_forTable.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
          //Build GT Row to match length of dataResults_forTable
          gtRow.push(null);
        }

        //Push words "Grand Total" into it's set position in gtRow - It must go into a column of type string.
        gtRow[labelColIndex] = labelCol;

        for (let i = 0; i < totalColumns.length; i++) {
          //Loop through groupColumns, test setting type for string.

          if (totalColumns[i].type === 'string') {
            //Convert to number from groupTotal result to string to match the column it's being pushed into
            gtRow[dataResults_forTable.getColumnIndex(totalColumns)] = String(groupTotal.getValue(0, i + 1));
          } else {
            //Otherwise push in the number value
            gtRow[dataResults_forTable.getColumnIndex(totalColumns)] = groupTotal.getValue(0, i + 1);
          }
        }
        //console.log('insertRow', insertRow);

        // insert complete gtRow with values into row position 0
        dataResults_forTable.insertRows(0, [gtRow]);

        //// set number formatting for dataResults_forTable row 0 (Grand Total row)
        //let formatter;
        //for (let i = 0; i < totalRow.totalColumns.length; i++) {
        //    formatter = dataColumn_format(totalRow.totalColumns[i].format);
        //    if (formatter !== null) {
        //        //This will override any previous formatting for the columns with totals.
        //        formatter.format(dataResults_forTable, dataResults_forTable.getColumnIndex(totalRow.totalColumns[i].id))
        //    }
        //}
        ////console.log('dataResults_forTable'); console.log(dataResults_forTable);

        // add formatting for grand total row to highlight && justify to right if of type number
        for (let j = 0; j < dataResults_forTable.getNumberOfColumns(); j++) {
          //if statement on column type for left right justification
          if (dataResults_forTable.getColumnType(j) === 'number') {
            dataResults_forTable.setColumnProperty(j, 'className', 'googleTableTextRight');
            dataResults_forTable.setProperty(0, j, 'className', 'googleTableTotalRow googleTableTextRight'); //stored in css file
          } else {
            dataResults_forTable.setProperty(0, j, 'className', 'googleTableTotalRow'); //stored in css file
          }
        }
        //console.log('dataResults_forTable', dataResults_forTable);
      } //END (groupTotal.getNumberOfRows() !== 0) {
    } //END if (hasTotalRow) {
    //#endregion

    //#region conditional formatting - if required
    let hasConditionalFormat = false;
    if (hasConditionalFormat) {
      dataResults_forTable = conditionalFormatting_default(dataResults_forTable, conditionalFormat);
    } //END if (hasConditionalFormat) {
    //#endregion

    var finalView_forTable = new google.visualization.DataView(dataResults_forTable);
    //console.log('finalView_forTable', finalView_forTable);

    // set reset sorting, set dataTable & draw chart
    table.setView(null); // reset in case sorting has been used via user click
    table.setDataTable(finalView_forTable); //includes any total row
    table.draw();

  } //END redrawChart()

}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
    <div id="categoryPicker"></div><br />
    
    <div id="div_proxyTable" style="display: none;"></div><br />

    <div id="div_table"></div><br /><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure exactly what should be accomplished with the proxy table,
but to prevent the select event from being added multiple times,
use a one time listener, here...

```
google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(proxyTable, 'ready', function() {
  console.log(".addListener(proxyTable, 'ready' - select");

  let clickGetFunc = true;
  if (clickGetFunc !== undefined || clickGetFunc !== null) {

    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(table, 'ready', function() {
      console.log(".addOneTimeListener(table, 'ready' - select");

      google.visualization.events.addListener(table.getChart(), 'select', function() {
        console.log(".addListener(table.getChart(), 'select' - selected");
        console.log("result of select");
        //lib_gcharts_selectedRowCol(table, json.tableChart.clickGetFunc);//(wrapperName, callback)
      });

    });
  }


  redrawTable();
});
```

Comment: I made edits tagged as UPDATED in the code snippet.  I think this does what I need but will re-verify tomorrow morning.  Thank you once again!

Comment: BTW...I typically use a dashboard to hold a hidden proxyTable and visible categoryPickers.  Then on ProxyTable ready event, retrieve the data in hidden proxyTable, and redraw with various interpretations of the data.  This allows me to have categoryPickers which are not necessarily visible in the end result table.

Comment: This worked perfectly until I tried to add in my lib_gcharts_selectedRowCol function which was not included in this post.  One step at a time.  I will post a separate question.